# Openpyxl throws no errors but no changes to workbook are being made?

Tags: openpyxl

I've been trying to make a job finder using beautiful soup, and now want to move what I find into an excel file. But even when I try running the simplest changes to a worksheet, like in the code below, nothing actually changes and there are no errors.

I've tried copying tutorial code from online, as I assumed it's my simple mistake (which it probably is), but there is still no change.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("PracticeWorkbook.xlsx") 
ws = wb.active
ws.cell(row=1, column=1,value='please work')

wb.save("PracticeWorkbook.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, bearing in mind that because you're using `load_workbook` you need to already have `'PracticeWorkbook.xlsx'` as an existing file.

Comment: Thanks, it already is an existing file. I actually just figured out that I needed to have the full file path down instead of just the name, not sure why though.